# Why does var test = false become true when you do test = !test?

Tags: javascript

Javascript newbie here and my mind is bending now.

```
var test = false
test = !test
// returns true
```

I know that the ! is a bang operator and changes a Boolean value to the opposite of what it currently is.

But I can't grasp what is going on in

```
test = !test
```

The variable test is pointing to the value false at first, but is this variable getting set to itself? It seems that the test variable is getting set to itself and then the bang operator applies making it true. But could both sides of a assignment operator be set the same variable?

Comment: `// returns false` - no it doesn't

Comment: It’s just like `x = x + 1`. Remember, first the right-hand side is evaluated, then it’s assigned to the left-hand side.

Comment: It returns true dude!

Comment: `!` is the not operator. For more details check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this step by step.

```
test =
```

You are now assigning `test` a new value

```
= ![...]
```

Which is the logical opposite of...

```
= !test
```

... the current value in `test`. What this code does in summary is to invert test and apply the result of that operation back on the variable itself, effectively changing it.

What might help understanding the whole operation is that `test`is **not** pointing at false but **is** false.

Answer (score 0):

It returns true. Maybe you should put a `;` at the end of the statements.
https://jsfiddle.net/dtpx1d5m/

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = false; // test = false
test = !test; // test = true (because `test` was `false`, now it's equal to opposite value: `true`)
```

And don't ignore semicolons at the end of rows.

Answer (score 0):

`var test = false`

Here you are setting the value of `test` to be false.

`test = !test`

First evaluated is the right side. So by reffering to `test` you receive its value.

Ultimatelly `test` is the same as `false`. So `!test` becomes `!false`, which is evaluated to `true`.

Thus your `test = !test` is the same as `test = !false` and finally becomes `test = true`

Answer (score 0):

You just assign variable test with new value, and the new value is !test.

```js
var test = false;
test = !test; //you assign new value to test, and old value will be replaced
document.getElementById('tes').value = test;
```

```html
<input type='text' id='tes'>
```